# Method definition gets 'syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to define a method in a model and on the last elsif line i get a syntax error stating "/app/models/purchase.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' elsif (self.invoices.sum(:current_balance) = 0 ^ ".

```
  def payment_status
    if self.invoices.blank?
      self.payment_status = "No Invoices"
    else
      if self.invoices.sum(:current_balance) > 0
        self.payment_status = "Open"
      elsif self.invoices.sum(:current_balance) < 0
        self.payment_status = "Overpaid"
      elsif self.invoices.sum(:current_balance) = 0
        self.payment_status = "Paid"
      end
    end
  end
```

I certainly do mean to use the equals sign there, so I I'm lost as to what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you __do not__ mean to do an assignment there.

Comment: I stand corrected. Now I just have to go back over it and figure out why the method I'm trying to define is coming back undefined.

Comment: All in all, this whole class of yours looks suspicious. Overriding database property getters to ninja-trigger setters with god knows what else side effects? Shady shit.

Comment: I can't disagree with you on that, but it's the only way I could think of that might work.

Comment: I am quite positive that a couple of `before_save` handlers would have done the job.

Comment: Also, what do you mean, "method is undefined". It is defined. There, we can see it. What is the _exact_ error message? Is it, perhaps, a "NoMethodError no method 'blah' for nil:NilClass"?

Comment: The error is:
NoMethodError undefined method `payment_status=' for #<Purchase:0x007fab3c5d0db0>
Did you mean?  payment_status

Comment: yeah, it doesn't help that you can't tell one error from another :) Apparently, there is no setter for payment_status in the Purchase class. You can't "define" it by assigning to it. Setters doesn't work like that.

Comment: Alright, then I am well and truly lost. I'll have to go read about setters and getters. Thanks for trying to help, yet again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure. Come back with other questions. But really take your time with the basics. It pays off! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  elsif self.invoices.sum(:current_balance) = 0
                                            ^---
```

that's an assignment operation. you want an equality test, which is `==`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. When I have the equality test == there I get a message stating that the method 'payment_status' is undefined. Which is funny to me as that's exactly what I'm trying to define.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clean up the code a little bit followed by an explanation:

```
def payment_status
  if invoices.blank?
    "No Invoices"
  elsif invoices.sum(:current_balance) > 0
    "Open"
  elsif invoices.sum(:current_balance) < 0
    "Overpaid"
  else
    "Paid"
  end
end
```

1. You don't need to use `self` in front of every function call unless there is a local variable with the same name and you need to differentiate them.
2. An if statement automatically returns the value that it "selects" based on the condition and functions automatically return their last statement.
3. You don't need to set `payment_status` each time. It will automatically be the return value (the last value of the function)

If you want to run this code only once, store the value in a variable, and use the function multiple times, you can [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) this with the following code:

```
def payment_status
  @payment_status ||= begin
    if invoices.blank?
      "No Invoices"
    elsif invoices.sum(:current_balance) > 0
      "Open"
    elsif invoices.sum(:current_balance) < 0
      "Overpaid"
    else
      "Paid"
    end
  end
```

For more examples on how/when to memoize [click here](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/) or [here](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/)

Comment: Perhaps, move the early return out of the memoization block?